# Angular / Firestore - Await a firestore document query

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, angularfire

I have a function in a service that's used to create a new document. One of the values for this new document needs to come from a value stored in another document.

How do i await the returned value from a document query (getDoc) before updating my new document?

The steps I imagined (please correct me if i'm wrong) would be:

1. Call `getDoc` function and return a value, let's say 'birthday'
2. Once this value has returned, call the `newDocument` function so that the `birthday` value can be used for the `new_value`

Function to add new document:

```
newDocument(g){
  const newID = this.afs.createId();
  this.afs.doc<Interface>(`col/${id}/col/${newID}`).set({
    new_value: // needs to come from other query
  });
}
```

Function that queries the document i need data from:

```
  getDoc(ID: string) {
    return this.afs.doc<Interface>(`col/${ID}`).valueChanges().pipe(shareReplay());
  }
```

Comment: As a test, i broke out of angularfire and instead used a native firestore query to query the document, and if it exists, call the document add function with the data. I think that's alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reading the official [angularfire documents doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md), where you can see a basic example to how query and manipulate documents.

In your case, you should await the `get` call on your document by converting it to a Promise or inside a `subscribe()` call. For example purposes, I put everything on the same function.

```
  async newDocument(){
    const ID = 'some_id';
    const docData = await this.afs.doc(`col/${ID}`).get().toPromise();  // Await the doc data
    const newID = this.afs.createId();
    this.afs.doc(`col/${id}/col/${newID}`).set({
      new_value: docData
    });
  }
```